# Path normalization with respect to NTFS reparse points (symlinks/directory junctions)?

Tags: c#, powershell, cmd

Unfortunately, I'm on Windows and I need POSIX [`realpath`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/realpath/).

Suppose that there's a dirpath variable in a CMD batch script:

```
FOODIR=D:/tmp/foo/bar/quux
```

where one or more middle components of the dirpath are [symlinks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006(v=vs.85).aspx) (*directory junctions* in Microsoft parlance):

```
[/cygdrive/d/tmp]$ cmd /C dir /Ad /l
 ...
 Directory of D:\tmp
...
2014-12-10  16:44    <SYMLINKD>     foo [D:\storage\foo.canonical]
```

How to write a function which will transform `%FOODIR%` into `D:/storage/foo.canonical/bar/quux`?

Any solutions welcome.

Comment: For existing, not empty files `GetFinalPathNameByHandle` should work.

Answer (score 0):

[GetFinalPathNameByHandle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16926224/2746150) worked for me.

Alternatively with Powershell 5+ you may traverse path up and resolve each folder. Check for `.LinkType in ('Junction', 'SymbolicLink')` and use `.Target[0]` with optional resolution for relative symlinks.